# Python : Wait certain time before calling the send_hook Discord for the same item

Tags: python, time, discord, stock

My program checks a number of items via URLs and calls a send_hook, when the item is in stock.
I would like my program to wait a certain time before calling the send_hook for the same item again. It should however continue to check the other URLs.
.. Is this possible?

Here is my program :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from discord import send_hook
from datetime import datetime

pid = ['PB00393363','PB00430691','PB00430699']

headers = {
    'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'
}

while True:
    for i in range(len(pid)):
    
    url = "https://www.ldlc.com/fr-be/fiche/{}.html".format(pid[i])

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)     
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    stock_statut = soup.find('div', class_='content').get_text().strip()            
    product_title = soup.find('h1').get_text().strip()
    
    price = soup.find_all('div', class_='price')[3].get_text()
    

    try:

        image_url = soup.find('img', {'id':'ctl00_cphMainContent_ImgProduct'})['src']
    
    except:
       
        image_url = soup.find('img', {'id':'ctl00_cphMainContent_ImgProduct'})['src']
        
    if stock_statut == 'En stock':
        print('[{}] En stock'.format(str(datetime.now())))
        
        send_hook(product_title, url, image_url, price)

    else:
        print('[{}] Rupture'.format(str(datetime.now())))
```

If you could help me that will make me happy.
Thank you!

Comment: Your code example is not quite clear to me. Where do I find the others requests in your example? There is no loop that could process multiple things.
Can you post an example that I can try out and be a bit more precise about what you want to achieve?

Comment: thank you for your answer here is my full program.

Comment: Ok, now we can go on: Your code seems a bit broken: 

1. There is no indentation behind the `for i in ..`.
2. You make two assignments to soap without doing something with soap in between.
Could you fix that?
In addition I don't understand your problem. When do you want to wait? Doesn't it continue after the send_hook?

Comment: I'm still just a beginner for programming in python. I don't quite understand some parts of how it works. My program continues without stopping. My problem that I want to solve is with the discord notification. When, for example, the program finds a product in stock, it sends the same notification several times. I just want that once it's sent waits before it gets sent back but if I use time.sleep () after send hook. My program stops and it does not continue for other requests.

Comment: To be more precise in my explanation I will give an example:
-I have 3 product to analyze
-It finds 1 in stock and the others out of stock for example. Once the 3 cases are analyzed the program starts again and it returns the same notification. This is where my problem comes from. When it loops back I want it not to send the same notification a second time but to wait a certain time before being sent while continuing to do the loop.
I don't know if I have been clear enough to you?

Comment: somewhat similar to this js code :

sendNotification(link, store);

    if (config.page.inStockWaitTime) {
      inStock[link.url] = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        inStock[link.url] = false;
      }, 1000 * config.page.inStockWaitTime);
    }

Comment: @jhinghaus Hello sir, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use pythons time module.

I just copied the whole of the code and added some lines to help you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from discord import send_hook
from datetime import datetime
import time

# Declare a wait time in seconds
wait_time = 30

pid = ['PB00393363','PB00430691','PB00430699']
# Use a dictionary associate each item with the time of the last find
# Init with 0 meaning long in the past
timed_pid = {p: 0 for p in pid}  

...

while True:
    # Wait some time. Multiple requests per second could be considered a DOS attack
    time.sleep(5)
    # do not iterate over the length
    #for i in range(len(pid)):
    # iterate the keys of the dict
    for p in timed_pid:
        # check the time passed since the last find
        if (time.time() - timed_pid[p]) < wait_time:
            # wait time has not passed: skip
            continue
    
        # use p directly for formating
        url = "https://www.ldlc.com/fr-be/fiche/{}.html".format(p)

        ...
        
        if stock_statut == 'En stock':
            print('[{}] En stock'.format(str(datetime.now())))
            # set the time of the current find
            timed_pid[p] = time.time()
            send_hook(product_title, url, image_url, price)

        else:
            print('[{}] Rupture'.format(str(datetime.now())))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting this error:
`if (time.time()-timed_pid[p]) < wait_time:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'time.struct_time'`

Comment: @Dilolcyy Sorry, you can just init with 0. I fixed that.

Comment: It's in order. I sincerely thank you for your help. You are a really good programmer.